# Composite C1: How do disable in page errors

Tags: c1-cms

When we roll out to production, we want to make sure the errors produced by Composite C1 aren't seen by users. This is an example of a forced Exception thrown by an MVC Function test that is rendered directly in the page.

[image: in page error]

The following is in the web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Errors/Site-Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Errors/Page-Not-Found" />    </customErrors>
<compilation debug="false" optimizeCompilations="false" targetFramework="4.6">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v5 we introduced a way to turn this feature off.

In ~/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config locate the element

/configuration/Composite.Core.Configuration.Plugins.GlobalSettingsProviderConfiguration/GlobalSettingsProviderPlugins/add

and the the attribute "prettifyRenderFunctionExceptions" to "false"

Source: https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/issues/130

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the timely response. It would be cool to have a production deployment check list from Composite team. I'm sure there are some other settings that would be of help for security, performance, and error logging.  Happy coding